# How we can have layout options at time of node creation just like we select in panels and display suite

Tags: panels, display-suite

How we can add layout selection option of display suite or panel during node creation. Any solution available. The layout selection should be at the time of node selection.

Comment: If I remember correctly, those layout options are for the entire content type, all  nodes of that content type, and not of individual nodes.

Comment: Any other options to have layout selection or drag an drop functionality for creating page.

Comment: But again, why would you want that here if it's going to affect all the other nodes? User might think this will only affect individual nodes and accidentally change for all others. So makes no sense to have that here, if you ask me.

Comment: If you need the layout to be different for each node, even when they belong to the same content type, then use [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is something like the Paragraphs module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs

It's a good solution for creating flexible, yet structured, content.

Take a look at this video for a good idea of the promises (and pitfalls) of this approach:

https://www.oomphinc.com/notes/2018/11/component-based-design-system-drupal-8-paragraphs/

**EDIT:** It's not a video, but here's a good place to start with Paragraphs for Drupal 7:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2605424

And since you are familiar with Display Suite, you might find this to be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40479965

Comment: Thanks for this. Any video for Drupal 7 and any guide on that.

Comment: I updated my answer with Drupal 7 info and tips on using Display Suite with Paragraphs. Good luck!